# Change default password in elasticsearch using .yml file

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

If I have an elasticsearch.yml config file is it possible to change the default password? What do I add in my .yml file to do that? Right now its `changeme`.

I am using `Elasticsearch 5.6.4`

My `.yml` file

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: "0.0.0.0"

http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : "OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
http.cors.allow-headers : "X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"
```

Comment: Which version? In 6.x there is no default password anymore.

Comment: 5.6.4 - for 6.x is there no basic auth?

Comment: There is but no default password anymore. You need to run setup-passwords from the CLI in 6.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the password via the API, like this:

```
POST _xpack/security/user/elastic/_password
{
  "password": "whatever"
}
```

Or, in case you forgot it or similar: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/i-lost-the-password-that-has-been-changed/91867/2

But you cannot do anything similar to the elasticsearch.yml file.

Answer (score 3):

`Andrei` answer works but can be problematic as the instance has to be running and you have to already be authenticated.

The following works for `6.7` and above and is more what I was looking for as a solution to boot elasticsearch with a custom password.

`echo "<boot_password>" | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add -xf bootstrap.password`

So my dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.1

RUN echo "<boot_password>" | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add -xf bootstrap.password

COPY ./config/elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Now you can connect using

`username: elastic`

`password: <boot_password>`